# What is the best way to build a path with equal distance between nodes?

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

I have a path in 2D space. But distances between noded are not equal.
I'm looking for an algorithm that adds nodes to the source path so that the distance between nodes will be equal.
What is the best practice?

Example picture:

[image]

Comment: So in path2, all the nodes have same distance between each other right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right!

Comment: I don't think that is possible given any set of 2D points, even if they are on a grid

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the different path lengths? As meowgoesthedog says, this will not work for any set of points.

Comment: I need this for any path.

Comment: As I have said, this is not possible for an arbitrary path; the best you can do is to compute the *"best fit"* solution, i.e. the one that is *closest* to the ideal (but unachievable)  equidistant solution

Comment: Note for example in your picture, that `distance03 == 0.5` while `distance04 == 0.447...` (gridsize units).

Comment: @pingul the picture is very approximate

Comment: You *cannot* achieve the ideal answer you want, as I have said repeatedly. It is geometrically impossible.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog so, what is the best practice to achieve _"best fit"_ solution?

Comment: Can I post as answer?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes, please.

Comment: @MikitaZacharčanka I edited my answer with some code. See if it produces the results you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is geometrically impossible for you to generate equidistant points for more than one arbitrary path segment - only possible if their lengths share a common divisor.

However, you can generate the closest matching set of points using the following method:

1. You need to first set the maximum number of points `N` you want on a path segment. This is to stop the algorithm from infinitely looping - because in the general case only an infinite number of divisions would give us the exact answer, and that is not what we want.

   - However before this can be applied, we need to check that `N + 1` is not less than the *ratio of the longest path to the shortest*. If it is then we need to adjust it.
2. For each path segment iterate to the maximum number of points `N`, calculating the division length `L` for each number. For each iterated value we shall define a `Cost` variable as the *sum of the total difference between the computed solution and the ideal*.
3. Then iterate through every other path segment. Divide its length `M` by `L` to give a ratio `R`:

   - If `R` is an integer, then for this segment an exact solution has been found. Add zero to `Cost`
   - Otherwise take `A = floor(R), B = ceil(R)`. Compute the two separate costs `cost_A = abs(M - L * A)` and similarly for `B`.
   - If `cost_A < cost_B`, take `C = A` as the optimal division count for this segment, and vice versa. Record `C`.
   - Take `min(cost_A, cost_B)` and add to `Cost`. Continue.
4. Remember to keep track of a list of optimal values for `C` for each path segment, and also the "working list" which records the current computation. Also keep track of a `min_Cost` variable.

   - If at the end of a main loop for each segment `Cost < min_Cost`, then update `min_Cost` and the optimal list.

---

The above description may seem a little vague. Here is some C# code - apologies as I'm not familiar with the details of C# Mono / Unity, so you may have to replace a few type names / function names here or there, but the gist of the algorithm is hopefully what you want.

```
public static int[] calculateOptimalSplitNumbers(Point[] path, int N)
{
   int no_segs = path.Length - 1;
   if (no_segs <= 1) return null;

   double[] lengths = new double[no_segs];
   for (int i = 0; i < no_segs; i++)
      lengths[i] = Vector.LengthOf(path[i + 1] - path[i]); // replace with the correct unity function?

   int max_ratio = Math.Floor(Math.Max(lengths) / Math.Min(lengths)) - 1;
   if (N < max_ratio)
      N = max_ratio;

   double min_Cost = double.MaxValue;
   int[] min_List = new int[no_segs];

   int[] cur_List = new int[no_segs];
   for (int i = 0; i < no_segs; i++)
   {
      double cost = 0.0;
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
         double L = lengths[i] / (j + 2);
         cur_list[i] = j + 1;

         for (int k = 0; k < no_segs; k++)
         {
            if (k == i) continue;

            double M = lengths[k],
                   R = M / L;
            // path is too short - put no points
            if (R < 1.0) {
               cur_list[k] = 0;
               cost += M - L;
            }

            int A = Math.Floor(R), 
                B = Math.Ceiling(R);
            double cost_A = Math.Abs(M - L * A),
                   cost_B = Math.Abs(M - L * B);
            if (cost_A < cost_B) {
               cur_list[k] = A;
               cost += cost_A;
            }
            else {
               cur_list[k] = B;
               cost += cost_B;
            }
         }
      }

      if (cost < min_Cost) {
         min_Cost = cost;
         System.Array.Copy(cur_List, min_List, no_segs);
      }
   }

   return min_List;
}
```

The code takes an array of path points and returns the number of points to put on each path segment. If you need any more explanation of the code just let me know and I will edit with some more comments.

Comment: Good workaround for the problem by redefining the problem within solvable range.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to share path normalizer utility (according to @meowgoesthedog approach) for using it in Unity3D:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Represents helper that normalizes the path in a way 
/// that distance between all nodes become almost equal.
/// </summary>
public static class PathNormalizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Normalizes the specified vector path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vectorPath">The vector path.</param>
    /// <param name="minSplitsBySegment">The minimum splits by segment.</param>
    public static Vector3[] Normalize(Vector3[] vectorPath, int minSplitsBySegment)
    {
        if (vectorPath.Length < 3)
        {
            return vectorPath;
        }

        var segmentsSplits = CalculateOptimalSplitNumbers(vectorPath, minSplitsBySegment);
        if (segmentsSplits == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Can't normalize path");
            return vectorPath;
        }

        List<Vector3> newPath = new List<Vector3>();

        for (int i = 1; i < vectorPath.Length; i++)
        {
            var split = segmentsSplits[i - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < split; j++)
            {
                var newNode = Vector3.Lerp(vectorPath[i - 1], vectorPath[i], (float)j / split);
                newPath.Add(newNode);
            }
        }

        newPath.Add(vectorPath[vectorPath.Length - 1]);
        return newPath.ToArray();
    }

    private static int[] CalculateOptimalSplitNumbers(Vector3[] path, int minSplitsBySegment)
    {
        int noSegs = path.Length - 1;
        if (noSegs <= 1) return null;

        float[] lengths = new float[noSegs];
        for (int i = 0; i < noSegs; i++)
            lengths[i] = Vector3.Distance(path[i + 1], path[i]);

        float minLenght = float.MaxValue;
        float maxLenght = 0;

        foreach (var length in lengths)
        {
            if (length < minLenght)
            {
                minLenght = length;
            }

            if (length > maxLenght)
            {
                maxLenght = length;
            }
        }

        int maxRatio = (int)Math.Floor(maxLenght / minLenght) - 1;
        if (minSplitsBySegment < maxRatio)
            minSplitsBySegment = maxRatio;

        double minCost = double.MaxValue;
        int[] minList = new int[noSegs];

        int[] curList = new int[noSegs];

        for (int i = 0; i < noSegs; i++)
        {
            double cost = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < minSplitsBySegment; j++)
            {
                double l = lengths[i] / (j + 2);
                curList[i] = j + 1;

                for (int k = 0; k < noSegs; k++)
                {
                    if (k == i) continue;

                    double m = lengths[k],
                        r = m / l;

                    // path is too short - put no points
                    if (r < 1.0)
                    {
                        curList[k] = 0;
                        cost += m - l;
                    }

                    int a = (int)Math.Floor(r),
                        b = (int)Math.Ceiling(r);
                    double costA = Math.Abs(m - l * a),
                        costB = Math.Abs(m - l * b);
                    if (costA < costB)
                    {
                        curList[k] = a;
                        cost += costA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curList[k] = b;
                        cost += costB;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (cost < minCost)
            {
                minCost = cost;
                Array.Copy(curList, minList, noSegs);
            }
        }

        return minList;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand correctly your variable is segments number between two points. I need similar solution but need to set maximum length between generated points.